# When is mChannelLayoutTag not kAudioChannelLayoutTag_UseChannelDescriptions

Tags: macos, audio, core-audio, audiounit, audiotoolbox

I was wondering if someone could tell me when mChannelLayoutTag in AudioChannelLayout is not kAudioChannelLayoutTag_UseChannelDescriptions, if the AudioChannelLayout is returned from AudioUnitGetProperty with kAudioUnitProperty_AudioChannelLayout([example](https://gist.github.com/ChunMinChang/ea74c8228745449873716e1d98ba956e/e20e7d23ad9be38fba31761217b397087b55a739#file-channellayout-cpp-L445)).

If it can be set via Audio MIDI Setup or other system apps, I will appreciate if you could tell me how to set it.

If it depends on hardware(e.g. sound card), I'll be grateful if you could tell me which device can return mChannelLayoutTag!=kAudioChannelLayoutTag_UseChannelDescriptions.

To discuss in a detailed way, I put my draft code on [gist here](https://gist.github.com/ChunMinChang/ea74c8228745449873716e1d98ba956e/e20e7d23ad9be38fba31761217b397087b55a739#file-channellayout-cpp-L217).

Thanks!